# Importing table that was created in python to docx

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, docx, python-3.7

I've created a table in python but I cannot import this table into docx, What should I do?

```
import docx 
import pandas as pd 
doc = docx.Document('Demo.docx')   

raw_data = {"Density" : [147.7, 148.6, 149.3, 153.3, 147.3, 147.8, 149.4, 147.8, 151.1, 148.5 ],
            "% Compaction":[95.4, 96.0, 95.3, 98.6, 95.1, 95.5, 96.4, 95.5, 97.5, 95.9],
            "Pass/Fail":["Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass",]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns= ['Density','% Compaction','Pass/Fail']) 
print(df)

docx.tables = df 
doc.save("Demo.docx")
```

Comment: You might be able to use json.dumps() I'm not too sure what do you want though the docx.tables into a doc file?

Comment: A few observations here: you're overwriting the package `docx.tables = ...`. Do you mean `doc.tables = `?? Also, without looking at the documentation I supect that you can't just write your *single table instance* to the document's `tables` collection. there is probably a `tables.add` method or a `table` class that you can instantiate and then add to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to dump the data into a csv file not into a docx (why a MS Word documentum...?)

My solution to this problem would be using pandas' Dataframe just like you did but with a little modification:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {"Density" : [147.7, 148.6, 149.3, 153.3, 147.3, 147.8, 149.4, 147.8, 151.1, 148.5 ], "% Compaction":[95.4, 96.0, 95.3, 98.6, 95.1, 95.5, 96.4, 95.5, 97.5, 95.9], "Pass/Fail":["Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass",]}
csv_file = "test_data.csv" #name of the file
df=pd.DataFrame(raw_data) #using pandas' Dataframe
df.to_csv(csv_file, index = False) #dumping data with headers, but without indexing
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Presumably they're building a table in a Word Document, because they need a word document. Your answer is fine for dumping to a CSV, but there's no reason to assume that's what OP wants :)

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#id1) object supports an `add_table` method, which creates the table placeholder in the document.

Your assignment statement is very wrong you're overwriting the package (`docx.tables`). Even allowing for that typo, `doc.tables` is the tables *collection*, so you're ovewriting that with a pandas DataFrame!

You need to use the `doc.add_table` method to create a table, and then fill its cells with values from your data frame.

There is no constructor for a `Table` object. It's simply added to the document via the `add_table` method.

Untested, but something like this:

```
table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=len(df.columns))
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
for i,cl in enumerate(hdr_cells):
    hdr_cells[i].text = df.columns[i]

for row in df.index:
    values = df.loc[row]
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    for i,v in enumerate(values):
        row_cells[i].text = v
```